# Can not connect to external database from ec2

Tags: php, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and I want to keep my project files in EC2 and database in another server. I have created instance, security groups and tested amazon test page. So I deployed my two projects

- 1 Codeigniter
- 1 laravel

Update database connectivity with database server IP address. But it's not connecting to server. I have allowed a remote host in my database server. But the result is the same.

Got below error

```
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '*****_user'@'ec2-54-146-119-134.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: You've said external database? Are both servers in AWS, and are they in the same VPC?

Comment: No database is out of aws, its in fastcomet

Comment: It seems that from the error that you're trying to connect to your EC2 host not your external DB

Comment: yes though i did not use public dns of ec2 in my database configuration. its taking by default

Comment: Have you got an example of your code?

Comment: which one? database connection?

Comment: Yeah just the code around where you perform, take out any sensitive information.

Comment: $db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => '***.**.***.***', /* database server ip address */
 'username' => '*********',
 'password' => '**********',
 'database' => '****************',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',

Comment: Can you add to question with formatting please :)

Comment: double-check the password, the Database server is reachable and the error related to password.
do ssh to the instance and run `mysql -h db_host -u db_user -pdb_passwor`, this will show the exact error message